# Extend the timeout after each click on react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Suppose there's the following simple component. When I click on the button, the message will change to `Clicked` for 1 second and then goes back to `-`. However, when I spam the button, I want the title to be `Clicked` but it should go back to `-` after the **last** click of the button. Basically, I want each click to expand the timeout.

If this was a simple JS function, I would just clear the interval after each click and set another timeout. However, I'm not sure how to achieve the same result using react hooks.

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import './index.css';

const Test = () => {
    const [message, setMessage] = useState("-");

    const buttonClick = () => {
        setMessage("Clicked");
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        if(message !== "-") {
            const id = setTimeout(() => {
                console.log("Running Interval");
                setMessage("-");
            }, 1000);

            return () => {
                console.log("Clearing Interval");
                clearTimeout(id);
            }
        }
    }, [message]);

    return (
        <article>
            <header>
                {message}
            </header>
            <button onClick={buttonClick}>button</button>
        </article>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the timeout ID into a ref, and then you can call `clearTimeout` on it at the very beginning of the click handler.

```js
const Test = () => {
    const [message, setMessage] = React.useState("-");
    const timeoutIdRef = React.useRef();
    const handleClick = () => {
        setMessage("Clicked");
        clearTimeout(timeoutIdRef.current);
        timeoutIdRef.current = setTimeout(() => {
            setMessage("-");
        }, 1000);
    };
    // cleanup, if desired
    // React.useEffect(() => clearTimeout(timeoutIdRef.current), []);
    return (
        <article>
            <header>
                {message}
            </header>
            <button onClick={handleClick}>button</button>
        </article>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Test />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Comment: Interesting. I tried to use something like that using a simple `let id` but I didn't know about the `useRef`. I'm reading about it now. So there's no way to achieve the same functionality using the `useEffect` hook?

Comment: In some cases you could put something like this into `useEffect` instead, but putting it all into one function is easier and means less code. In this situation, another problem with `useEffect` is that it'd only run when `message` changes, but that won't change on subsequent quick clicks.

Comment: Thank you. Yes. I tried that as well (clearing interval on click and using useEffect) basicall, it would only work if I clicked the button once (obviously). Thank you. I read about the `useRef` and it's exactly made for these kinds of situation so I imagine it's the best solution.